# Reading a text file with C++ to read in the value that follows a specific key word

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am attempting to write a generic text file reader in C++17 that will search a text file, line by line, for a specific key word and the code should read in the data point that follows that key word.  I am writing it with a template function within a class so that it can read in any data type.  In this example lets say that I have the following text file titled `test.txt`.

```
- test.txt file
integer key: 4
Float key: 6.04876
Double Key: 12.356554545476756565
String Key: test
```

The header file containing the template class looks like this.  In this case the `ReadTextFile` class inherits another class to assist with 
checking the file status.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

#ifndef read_files_hpp
#define read_files_hpp

class FileStatus
{
public:
    template <class container>
    bool file_exists(const container& file_name);
    template <class file_container>
    bool is_file_open(const file_container& file);
};
template <class container>
bool FileStatus::file_exists(const container& file_name)
    std::ifstream ifile(file_name.c_str());
    return (bool)ifile;
}

template <class file_container>
bool FileStatus::is_file_open(const file_container& file)
{
    return file.is_open();
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------


class ReadTextFile : public FileStatus
{
public:
    template <class dtype, class container1, class container2>
    dtype read_key_words(const container1& file_name, const
                         container2& key_word);
};

template <class dtype, class container1, class container2>
dtype ReadTextFile::read_key_words(const container1& file_name,
                                   const container2& key_word)
{
    int j = 3;
    if (bool i = file_exists(file_name) != 1) {
        std::cout << "FATAL ERROR: " << file_name <<
        " not found" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::ifstream file(file_name);
    if (is_file_open(file))
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(file, line))
        {
            std::cout << line.c_str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
// ================================================================
// ================================================================
#endif
```

The calling program `main.cpp` looks like this;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "read_files.hpp"
int main() {
    std::string file_name("../data/unit_test/keys.txt");
    std::string key_word("integer key:");
    int j;
    j = txt_file.read_key_words<int>(file_name, key_word);
}
```

In this test case the class is being instantiated as type `int` so until the program is completely written I am returning the variable `int j = 3;` from the function `read_key_words()`.  At present the code can read the file `test.txt` which is in the same directory and correctly read in each line.  I would like the code to parse each line to recognize if the phrase `integer key:` is present and then read the variable that follows it, as the data type that the function is instantiated for, which in this case is an integer.  How can I make this happen within the code?

Comment: In general, templates don’t work well when you are reading data, where the data itself describes its type. You need a map of reading functions where the key is the string that precedes the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you go through each line, search for the key word. If it's found, grab the next data that constitutes this type:

```c++
dtype j;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  if (auto pos = line.find(key_word); pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::stringstream iss(line.substr(pos + key_word.size()));
    iss >> j;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: While that is a great solution it is too specific.  I gave four examples of what the key words could be, but the key words could be an infinite number of string.  Instead of `float key:` it could have been `square` or `read this value`.

Comment: @Jon I mistakenly overlooked that you were also specifying the key word. You can replace `line.find(phrase)` with `line.find(key_word)` and `pos + phrase.size()` with `pos + key_word.size()`

Comment: I just found a solution, but I have to admit this one is a bit more elegant.  O.K., let me ask one more question, if necessary I will ask. completely new question instead of tacking on to this one.  What if the text file line reads `Array key: 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4` and I want to read all the values after `Array key:` into a vector.  Is there a way that your solution can be modified to read the remaining values as scalars or arrays?

Comment: @Jon Sure. Just do `while (iss >> j) v.push_back(j)`

Comment: This method didn't work exactly for me, but a variation of it is working very well. I will post it later today, but in the mean time I will up-rate you for having helped me solve this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Could you elaborate on what `if (auto pos = line.find(key_word); pos != std::string::npos)` means?

Comment: C++17 introduced a new kind of `if` statement. It allows you to declare a variable before the conditional statement. It simply allows for shorter and more consise code. If you're asking what that code does, it looks for the index where `key_word` begins in the string, and the conditional just checks if that search was sucessful. The `if` statement only executes if the search found `key_word` in `line`.